# imgur api image uploading cross origin resource sharing error

Tags: javascript, html, css, imgur

hope you all doing fine,

currently i am working on a small html static project and i have image uploading there so i used imgur api, i tested it out on postman it seems pretty okay, but when i try to code it like that

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Client-ID ******");
myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("image", image);

var requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata,
  redirect: "follow",
};

fetch("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload", requestOptions)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

i only got this error

```
cross origin resource sharing error header disallowed preflight response
```

am i doing something wrong here